# Problem with exporting data to excell with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem .I want to export my data book from my database to excell with symfony.
I tried to use phpSpreadSheet . My function works but just for one value(the last value).I don't understand why I can't retrieve all my values.If you have any idea , it will be great.

/**
     * @Route("/create",name="createE")
     *
     *
     */

```
public function createSpreadsheet(){
    $this->allExcel();
    return $this->render('admin/book/sendExcelOk.html.twig');


}
public function allExcel(){

    $books =$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Book::class)->findAll();
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Export Books');

    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Book')->mergeCells('C1:D1');
    $columnNames = [
        'Title',
        'Author',
        'PublicationDate',
        'Format',
        'Language'
    ];
    $columnLetter = 'A';
    foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
        // Allow to access AA column if needed and more
        $columnLetter++;
        $sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter.'3', $columnName);
    }


    foreach ($books as $book) {
        $columnValues = [
            [$book->getTitle(),
            $book->getAuthor(),
           $book ->getPublicationDate(),
           $book->getFormat(),
           $book->getLanguage()],

        ];
    }

    $i = 4; // Beginning row for active sheet
    $columnLetter = 'A';
    foreach ($columnValues as $columnValue) {

        foreach ($columnValue as $value) {
            $columnLetter++;
            $sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter.$i, $value);

        }
        $i++;

    }

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $nombre =Book::$nombreExcell++;
    $name ="Book ".$nombre;
    $writer->save($name.'.xlsx');
    return $spreadsheet;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable `$columnValues` instead of appending new values to the array. Try to initialize the array first and add the values to the array (`$columnValues[] = …`) like this:

```php
$columnValues = [];

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $columnValues[] = [
        $book->getTitle(),
        $book->getAuthor(),
        $book ->getPublicationDate(),
        $book->getFormat(),
        $book->getLanguage(),
    ];
}
```